# Iterative INSERT about dates in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

I'm having a bit of performance problem due to some iterative inserts I do in my database.

It's a booking website where each customer can set the price of its flat for each day of the year, by timespans.

At the moment, I loop in PHP from start_date to end_date and set the price accordingly, but for long periods it takes a really long time to do so.

Since that for each period, the price is the same, I wanted to know if MySQL had a way to do that without passing through a heavy PHP loop with multiple inserts, and do that with one query instead.

```
CREATE table disponibility (
    dispo_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    dispo_full_date varchar(10),
    dispo_day varchar(2),
    dispo_month varchar(2),
    dispo_year varchar(4),
    dispo_price INT
)
```

So the user set the price from date_from and date_to, and I need the datas in the following format:

dispo_full_date => date in format dd/mm/yyyy
dispo_day => day from the date in format dd
dispo_month => month from the date in format mm,
dispo_year => year from the date in format yyyy,
dispo_price => the price, just an INT

Is there a way to do that with just SQL ? Especially since the number of days in a month is different for each month or even depending on the year for february ...

Answer (score 0):

change your table to have `DATETIME dispo_start_date` and `DATETIME dispo_end_date`, then use `SELECT BETWEEN`.

Just don't store every single day and use `DATE`(`TIME`) fields (with index).

That should be way faster.

Comment: The thing is that I need the data in the format I said hence the problem with slowlyness

Comment: I mean, you can hold the same amount of information by less data in the table, should make it way faster. You don't need day,month,year + full_date